# Using the original instance of a JFrame

Tags: java, instance, multiple-instances, instanceof

I have two Java classes; `mcveF1` and `mcveF2`. The code below disables when run opens a `JFrame` with a singular `JButton` on it. This button opens a second `JFrame` and disables the first. Similarly this frame has a singular `JButton` on it. This button should close the second frame and re-enable the first frame. However an exception is thrown, `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I believe this is because I am creating a new instance of `mcveF1` instead of using the current one. I am unaware of how to fix this and would appreciate any help in fixing it.

**`mcveF1`**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class mcveF1
{
    public JFrame myMainWindow = new JFrame("Frame 1");

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

    //Variables and Components
    JButton openFrame = new JButton("Open new frame");

    public void runGUI()
    {
        myMainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        myMainWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

        createSortTestPanel();

        myMainWindow.getContentPane().add(panel2);

        myMainWindow.setVisible(true);
        myMainWindow.pack();
        myMainWindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(myMainWindow.getBounds().getSize()));
        myMainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void createSortTestPanel()
    {
        MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("", "[grow]");
        panel2.setLayout(layout);

        openFrame.addActionListener(new buttonAction());
        panel2.add(openFrame);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        mcveF1 f1 = new mcveF1();
        f1.runGUI();
    }

    class buttonAction implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            myMainWindow.setEnabled(false);
            mcveF2 f2 = new mcveF2();
            f2.runGUI();
        }
    }
}
```

**`mcveF2`**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class mcveF2
{
    JFrame myMainWindow = new JFrame("Frame 2");

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

    //Variables and Components
    JButton closeFrame = new JButton("Close");
    mcveF1 f1;

    public void runGUI()
    {
        myMainWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

        createSortTestPanel();

        myMainWindow.getContentPane().add(panel2);

        myMainWindow.setVisible(true);
        myMainWindow.pack();
        myMainWindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(myMainWindow.getBounds().getSize()));
        myMainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void createSortTestPanel()
    {
        MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("", "[grow]");
        panel2.setLayout(layout);

        closeFrame.addActionListener(new buttonAction());
        panel2.add(closeFrame);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        mcveF2 f2 = new mcveF2();
        f2.runGUI();
    }

    class buttonAction implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            myMainWindow.dispose();
            f1.myMainWindow.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The null pointer exception is shown in this picture as per PM77-1's request.

[image: null pointer exception]

Comment: What do you have on line # **54** in your `mvceF2.java` file?

Comment: @PM77-1 `f1.myMainWindow.setEnabled(true);`

Comment: `f1` is `null` in your `mcveF2` class. You never initialized it.

Comment: @PM77-1 How would I do that without creating a new instance of `mcveF1`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why do you need two virtually identical classes?

Comment: @PM77-1 In my actual program I am trying to open a settings frame and disabling the main frame until the settings frame is closed. These are only very similar because I took out the code required to show the problem I am getting

Comment: Can you use a modal dialogue?

Comment: @PM77-1 I suppose I could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a constructor in your class `mcveF2`

```
public class mcveF2() {
   public mcveF2(mcveF1 f1) {
      this.f1 = f1;
   }
```

Then pass instance of mcveF1 to this constructor in button action listener.

```
class buttonAction implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            myMainWindow.setEnabled(false);
            mcveF2 f2 = new mcveF2(mcveF1.this);
            f2.runGUI();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you

Comment: @Dan I had the exact problems when I was a student :)